# Xpages accessing data on a database which does not allow anonymous access

Tags: xpages

I have an Internet facing  Domino server in our DMZ on which customers log support requests, the customer is required to authenticate, ie. anonymous access is not available. I have developed internal 'wallboards & dashboards' for our support staff, which need to be displayed using web browsers. To allow the wallboard/dashboard web pages to open without authentication I point them at a replica of the database on the second 'internal' server, I do not force a  'consistent access control list' between the replicas and allow Anonymous access to this replica. My problem being that replication across the servers is every 20 mins, so the wallboards are up to 20 minutes behind. I cannot point my wallboard 'Computed Fields' etc at the 'live' database in the DMZ as it throws an error presumably because there is no authentication.

**Typical error:**

```
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=57: 'db.getView().getAllEntries()' is null
JavaScript code
1: return db.getView("$FaultStatsDayOpen").getAllEntries().getCount().toFixed();
```

I imagine I have some of the  concepts wrong of how to achieve this. But basically I need XPages from the internal server to be able to retrieve data from views and documents on the DMZ server even though it does not allow Anonymous access.

I can't seem to find this on any of the forums, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sessionAsSigner allows the code to access databases on any servers in the same domain using the access of the ID signing the XPage. Remember that all design elements included in the XPage need to be signed by the same ID.

If the server is in another domain, you'll need to replicate the database across a server in the same domain in order to access it.

Comment: Paul is right.  sessionAsSigner can be used for this.  I've done this as well.  The code will run with the rights of the signer.  I believe you also want to make sure that the servers trust each other in the config document.

Comment: Brilliant, many hours wasted on that, first time I have used this forum.
So pleased, thanks Paul and David, really appreciated.

Comment: Mark, remember to accept the correct answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: Accepted done, sorry newbie, Thanks for editing Jerodev